# How can i select GREATEST several columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table

| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4 | COL_5 | COL_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 9 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 4 |
| 8 | 6 | 8 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 7 |

How can I SELECT GREATEST only four column ?

The result is given below

| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 9 | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| 8 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 |

Comment: Perhaps first unpivot, pick 4 greatest, and then pivot?

Comment: @jarlh is a genius and understands what you're asking. I'm - on the other hand - not, and I'd like to see you **explaining** rules that lead from source to target. Why is [ID = 1, COL_1] = 9? Why is [ID = 1, COL_2] = 7? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @jarlh's answer, you can `UNPIVOT`, index the unpivoted values and order them and then `PIVOT` the top 4 values back:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn,
         value
  FROM   table_name
         UNPIVOT(value FOR name IN (col_1, col_2, col3, col4, col5, col6))
)
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rn IN (1 AS col_1, 2 AS col_2, 3 AS col_3, 4 AS col_4));
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, col_1, col_2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 2, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

---

If you want unique values then use `DENSE_RANK` (rather than `ROW_NUMBER`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn,
         value
  FROM   table_name
         UNPIVOT(value FOR name IN (col_1, col_2, col3, col4, col5, col6))
)
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rn IN (1 AS col_1, 2 AS col_2, 3 AS col_3, 4 AS col_4));
```

Which outputs:

| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o7mTOgMr)

Answer (score 2):

First unpivot (`with unpivited as...`.)

Pick 4 greatest for each id (row_number/dense_rank over partition.)

And finally pivot (case expressions / group by):

```
with unpivoted as (
    select id, col_1 as col from t
    union all
    select id, col_2 as col from t
    union all
    select id, col_3 as col from t
    union all
    select id, col_4 as col from t
    union all
    select id, col_5 as col from t
    union all
    select id, col_6 as col from t
)
select id,
       max(case when rn = 1 then col end) col_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then col end) col_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then col end) col_3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then col end) col_4
from
(
  select id, col, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by col desc) rn
  from unpivoted
) dt
where rn <= 4
group by id;
```

Do `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`, to get four greatest distinct values. (Both versions included in the dbfiddle.) Thanks to @SelVazi for the tip.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/857tbMiK

ISO/ANSI SQL query, since I don't know Oracle very well. The following optional ISO/ANSI SQL features are used:
T611, Elementary OLAP operations
F591, Derived tables
T121, WITH (excluding RECURSIVE) in query expression

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` should be used to prevent getting duplicates https://dbfiddle.uk/d95z1l2T

Comment: @SelVazi, yes, of course!

Comment: But what if the table has more than 10 million rows?

Comment: @AleksRous, do you mean performance wise? I have no idea. Compare the different queries you get here and come back with the results - I'd find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without pivoting using `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 0 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 0 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 0 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 0 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 0 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 0 THEN col_6
       END AS col_1,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 1 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 1 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 1 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 1 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 1 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 1 THEN col_6
       END AS col_2,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 2 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 2 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 2 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 2 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 2 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 2 THEN col_6
       END AS col_3,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 3 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 3 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 3 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 3 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 3 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 3 THEN col_6
       END AS col_4
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         col_1,
         CASE WHEN col_1 < col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END r1,
         col_2,
         CASE WHEN col_2 <= col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END r2,
         col_3,
         CASE WHEN col_3 <= col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_3 <= col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END r3,
         col_4,
         CASE WHEN col_4 <= col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_4 <= col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_4 <= col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_4 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_4 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END r4,
         col_5,
         CASE WHEN col_5 <= col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_5 <= col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_5 <= col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_5 <= col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_5 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END r5,
         col_6,
         CASE WHEN col_6 <= col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_6 <= col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_6 <= col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_6 <= col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN col_6 <= col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END r6
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 2, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

---

If you want unique values then you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 0 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 0 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 0 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 0 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 0 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 0 THEN col_6
       END AS col_1,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 1 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 1 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 1 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 1 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 1 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 1 THEN col_6
       END AS col_2,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 2 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 2 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 2 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 2 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 2 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 2 THEN col_6
       END AS col_3,
       CASE
       WHEN r1 = 3 THEN col_1
       WHEN r2 = 3 THEN col_2
       WHEN r3 = 3 THEN col_3
       WHEN r4 = 3 THEN col_4
       WHEN r5 = 3 THEN col_5
       WHEN r6 = 3 THEN col_6
       END AS col_4
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         col_1,
         r1
         - CASE WHEN r1 > r2 THEN e2 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r1 > r3 THEN e3 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r1 > r4 THEN e4 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r1 > r5 THEN e5 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r1 > r6 THEN e6 ELSE 0 END AS r1,
         col_2,
         r2
         - CASE WHEN r2 > r1 THEN e1 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r2 > r3 THEN e3 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r2 > r4 THEN e4 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r2 > r5 THEN e5 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r2 > r6 THEN e6 ELSE 0 END AS r2,
         col_3,
         r3
         - CASE WHEN r3 > r1 THEN e1 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r3 > r2 THEN e2 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r3 > r4 THEN e4 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r3 > r5 THEN e5 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r3 > r6 THEN e6 ELSE 0 END AS r3,
         col_4,
         r4
         - CASE WHEN r4 > r1 THEN e1 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r4 > r2 THEN e2 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r4 > r3 THEN e3 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r4 > r5 THEN e5 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r4 > r6 THEN e6 ELSE 0 END AS r4,
         col_5,
         r5
         - CASE WHEN r5 > r1 THEN e1 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r5 > r2 THEN e2 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r5 > r3 THEN e3 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r5 > r4 THEN e4 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r5 > r6 THEN e6 ELSE 0 END AS r5,
         col_6,
         r6
         - CASE WHEN r6 > r1 THEN e1 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r6 > r2 THEN e2 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r6 > r3 THEN e3 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r6 > r4 THEN e4 ELSE 0 END
         - CASE WHEN r6 > r5 THEN e5 ELSE 0 END AS r6
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           col_1,
           CASE WHEN col_1 < col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_1 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r1,
           0 AS e1,
           col_2,
           CASE WHEN col_2 < col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_2 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r2,
           CASE WHEN col_2 = col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e2,
           col_3,
           CASE WHEN col_3 < col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_3 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r3,
           CASE WHEN col_3 = col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_3 = col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e3,
           col_4,
           CASE WHEN col_4 < col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_4 < col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_4 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_4 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_4 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r4,
           CASE WHEN col_4 = col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_4 = col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_4 = col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e4,
           col_5,
           CASE WHEN col_5 < col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 < col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 < col_6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r5,
           CASE WHEN col_5 = col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 = col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 = col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_5 = col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e5,
           col_6,
           CASE WHEN col_6 < col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 < col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 < col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 < col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 < col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS r6,
           CASE WHEN col_6 = col_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 = col_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 = col_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 = col_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + CASE WHEN col_6 = col_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e6
    FROM   table_name
  )
)
```

Which outputs:

| ID | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 | COL_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s9LvaDWC)